# Group or Group By support is not available for mongodb yii2

Tags: mongodb, yii2, mongodb-query, grouping

I am using the https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb package for my project while using ActiveDataProvider in Yii2 I am not able to add a group or groupBy condition in the query.